# How can I remote debug on another workgroup machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, managed, remote-debugging

I have used the "Attach to process" function within VS 2008 many times, but never actually on a remote machine. Now I have to do it and I already read a bunch about it on the net. After playing around a bit I've reached a point where I am not quite sure how to proceed. First of all, here's a quick list of what I've done so far:

Test machine (Win XP Pro SP3 x86):

- Install Msvsmon
- Change local policy for local accounts to "Classic - local users authenticate as themselves"
- Deactivated the windows firewall (yeah, not a great idea, but to avoid any port problems)
- Planted a copy of the application that is to be debugged including pdb files
- Created a user account that has the same name and password as on my dev machine
- Made sure the new created account is admin and has permission for remote debugging

VS host machine (Vista Home Premium x64 SP2, VS 2008 pro SP1)

- Deactivate firewall
- Made sure I can access the test machine via UNC path (works)

So, network communication works. Firewalls are off. Msvsmon is running on the test machine. But when I try to connect via "Attach to process" and enter the computer name of the test machine, I get this (translated from German):

> The connection to the visual studio
>   remote debug monitor with the name
>   "TESTMACHINE" could not be
>   established. Visual Studio remote
>   debugger does not support that windows
>   version.

It took a while until I found out that "windows version not supported" actually is trying to say "authentification error".

I even tried connection using "Remote without authentification" instead of "Standard", even though it won't work for me since I need to debug managed code. So I adjusted Msvsmon accordingly and the connection worked (I could select processes, but of course I could not really debug). So that makes me believe I'm having an authentification problem.

**So finally, my question:**

How do I set up users/authentification on both machines so I can remotely debug managed code within the same workgroup?

The local user names are the same, but how do I allow "DEVMACHINE\me" to remote debug on a machine where "me" is actually "TESTMACHINE\me"?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. It seems that the remote deugger does not run on Vista Home Premium (!), as can be read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/9457e157-2139-41fe-bdb6-9891ff9330ae):

> Remote debugging does NOT support
>   Vista Home Premium. Remote Debugging
>   requires an operating system that
>   supports full Windows Authentication.
>   In some future version of Visual
>   Studio, we hope to support other forms
>   of authentication. However, we are
>   currently deeply tied to Windows
>   Authentication.
>   For now there are two options - buy a
>   business edition of Windows or debug
>   locally.

Personally, I believe this is ridiculous - I actually have a Vista Business license, but Home Premium was pre-installed on my dev machine and I just left it there.